# Play a list of audio files in HTML

Tags: html, audio

I have three audio files (`audio1.mp3, audio2.mp3 and audio3.mp3`)

I need to play `audio1.mp3` first, after it finishes `audio2.mp3` needs to start immediately (i.e. without user interaction), finally `audio3.mp3` after `audio2.mp3` finished.

`audio1.mp3` --> `audio2.mp3` --> `audio3.mp3`

What is the best way to achieve this behaviour in current browsers?

Preferably without using any plugins (Flash, Java, etc) - Javascript libraries (e.g. jQuery) are fine

Answer (score 3):

You can use the HTML 5 audio tag like this

```
<audio id="player" controls autoplay>
<source src="audio1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

this will autoplay the first song.

then you can bind the player's `ended` event using javascript like this

```
var audio = $("#player")
audio.addEventListener('ended',function(){
        audio.src = "new url";// you can probably load this from an array of songs URL that you can maintain 
        audio.pause();
        audio.load();
        audio.play();
    });
```

This will load the new url in the player and autoplay the next song.

Check these links for more info
[link1](http://jonhall.info/how_to/create_a_playlist_for_html5_audio) [link2](https://web.archive.org/web/20141010114824/https://lastrose.com/html5-audio-video-playlist/)

[additional example](http://jonhall.info/examples/html5_audio_playlist_example.html)

Comment: link 2 is just what I was looking for.